# Can I copy my u-lock key?

Tags: lock

I have an OnGuard u-lock with only one key.  I contacted OnGuard about getting a backup, but it requires a serial number which was included with the original packaging.  The number is not on the lock or key itself.

So now I'm wondering if some locksmiths can copy such keys.

I realize this description is inadequate, but for what its worth, the shaft of the key is fairly rectangular.

Comment: Simple thing to do is to ask.  A good locksmith can copy most styles of keys, including "barrel" keys.  The only "gotcha" is whether they can get the blank.  (In the US there's generally no legal restriction on copying keys, even if stamped "Do Not Copy". Though state laws may vary and some locksmiths may balk at some keys.)

Comment: It may be cost prohibitive. Procuring a fancy blank and, presuming they have the equipment to cut it, getting a copy made, may run into the $30-$50 range. Definitely see if it is an option.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - You should make your comment an answer. Otherwise, I'm likely to copy and paste and claim the reputation. J/k. I wouldn't really do that but  serioiusly, I don't think a better answer could be given.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what kind of key is used on your specific lock.  The only image I can find of a OnGuard key shows it to be a slotted key similar to recent automotive keys, so most locksmiths should have the equipment to duplicate it.  The only question is whether they can get the correct blank.

Locksmiths can also duplicate the barrel-style keys used on many older bike locks, if they can find the right blank.

But I see a cheap OnGuards available at Target for $19.95 (with others ranging up to $80), while the new key is likely to cost upwards of $10.  So it may be best to just buy another lock (which comes with at least two keys, sometimes four).

Comment: Might it be better not to buy another lock to reduce waste?

Answer (score 2):

Many ulock manufacturers have a unique serial number or key code to make keys for your lock.

You can often register your keys with the company or simply request duplicates from them. There typically is a charge.

Kryptonite puts the key code on the key, on guard gives you a key code card with the box, other manufacturers vary.

[On guard lock registration](http://www.onguardlock.com/?page_id=180)
[Kryptonite key order page](http://www.kryptonitelock.com/Pages/OrderKeys.aspx)

Also, I found [Lokitt](http://lockitt.com/ReplacementKeys.htm) which offers key duplication services for ABUS/On Guard/Mul-T-Lock keys. They can make keys with key code or they can duplicate from an existing key.

Answer (score -1):

For Kryptonite: if you know the key # and the lock name/type they can duplicate it for $12 - one key; $20 for 2. $5 for each additional key

Comment: The original question explicitly said that they have a different brand and lack the magic number.