# Lock bike key go in but doesn't turn?

Tags: lock

From few days my lock bike key go in but doesn't turn to lock or unlock with one key.
I tried a second key and it go in and turn around normally they 2 key are similar and no rust on them.
I am afraid that one day I'm outside and key doesn't work.
What I should do if I face this problem ?

Comment: Have you checked this thread for some recommendations? https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/8262/how-to-deal-with-lock-that-keeps-jamming?rq=1

Comment: Bottom line: Check the lubrication tips there and start using the replacement key, instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with lock that keeps jamming?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/8262/how-to-deal-with-lock-that-keeps-jamming)

Comment: What brand? One thing not mentioned at the other question (or not that I can quickly find) is that with some locks, such as my Kryptonite series 2, a worn key can go in too far.  If mine won't turn I have to back the key out a hair's breadth then turn it